# Can't update Android SDK tools to rev13

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

When I try to update my SDK to the latest version, i get the following error:

`A Folder failed to be moved. On windows this typically means that a program is using that folder (for example Windows Explorer or your anti-virus software.) Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus software or close any running programs that may be accessing the directory 'C:\adt\android-sdk\tools'. When ready, press YES to try again.`

I checked with Process Explorer what processes use that directory and, surprise surprise, it's the SDK Manager that I use for the update.

Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved in Android SDK Tools rev14.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same kind of error when i was trying to installing SDK, later on i found that there is a Kaspersky anti-virus installed in my machine and due to it, android is giving me this error.

Once i have paused the Kaspersky security service then i was successful to download the SDK and installation for the same.

So my clue is you should stop any antivirus service.

Comment: I'm using F-Secure and I've already tried disabling it. Besides, the process that's using the directory is java.exe, not anything related to F-Secure.